# pkcs11 sso (using prior windows login with smartcard)

Tags: java, windows, ssl, pkcs#11

I wish to do the following:

1. Login or unlock my windows account with a smartcard (I know how). The smartcard prompts for PIN.
2. Then access a java software inside the account - and I want to use the same smartcard during its operation. However, I don't want it to prompt for PIN, but rather rely on the prior windows authentication.

Question: is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you just want to check if the current user has already been authenticated with the specific smartcard? - Or do you want to use other smartcard functions, such as digitally signing or decrypting data?

Comment: Second option. I want to be able to use the smartcard for encrypting /decrypting - as if the application prompted the user itself.

Comment: That would be quite a security risk, don't you think? - If any application could access the smartcard functions w/o the user's approval via PIN ...

Comment: In that case, the entire idea of SSO is a big risk not worth taking? 

Also, It is not as if the user hasn't logged in an initialized connection with the card. He did so on the OperatingSystem level. I wish to use that connection again.

Comment: Ok, now I've got your point :) - SSO by itself is not that bad, I thought you wanted to use explicit smartcard functions. - However, I don't know if/how Windows SSO can be leveraged from Java, sorry.

Comment: Technically it's possible. There is nothing in whole smartcard business what prevents from caching PIN. Actually, while we integrating smartcards in a windowsmobile product, we worked with smartcard readers provider to implement this functionality. However, it could be big security risk (as example malware will be able to use   your smartcard without you knowing it).

Comment: It appears this flaw in inherent, as one could argue that DDL-injection to the pkcs implementation could capture the PIN and broadcast it to the world.

So, your suggestion is for me to dll-inject myself to be able to retreive the PIN.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to patch your existing login procedures, perhaps its worth it to look at pGina (http://pgina.org/), as it is a modular replacement for the GINA part of Windows.

Comment: Okay. Nice. Will it allow my application to get access to certificates stored in smartcard in order for me to authenticate to a server?

Comment: If you write your own handler, sure :)

Comment: OK.

1. Are you familiar with SSO? Is using pgina easier?

2. Say I have used pgina - will the logic graphics change or can they remain the same? 

3. If a write a handler - will it be able to decrypt my information and so how do I get this information? inter-process communication?

Answer (score 0):

coming from [Incorparating SSO in addition/instead SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14106087/696632):

1. When sign in into Windows with your smartcard, it peforms a [`pkinit`](http://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Pkinit_configuration) and obtains a Kerberos TGT for you.
2. When you access a further resource that TGT is used and a Kerberos service ticket is created. No smartcard cert involved.
3. However, if you want to use the the smartcard in your app, you perform client cert auth and **not** Kerberos therefore the app **must** prompt you for your PIN.