# SSO confusion - incorporating SSL difficulties

Tags: java, windows, single-sign-on, smartcard, josso

I have a WebSphere on AIX server,
and a simple java client on windows XP (connects to server over http).
I would like to incorporate SSL for client autherization. Mainly, I have a smartcard reader.

The only problem is - the smartcard is used already once to access Windows and we would like to save the trouble for the client to re-enter PIN during client application startup.

I started reading a lot about SSO - which I was assured can help my problem. This led me to reading about WebSphere's support for SPENGO - in their redbooks. Problem is it involves a lot of support from the Active directory people - and they are not keen on helping - and also I fear they're envolvement can slow down the incorporation.

So now I am looking into OpenSSO, WAFFLE, JOSSO and other frameworks that may help me.

But wait - this all seems like a major overspec. All I wanted was to save my client a second prompt to the smartcard.
What I really want is a method - one of the following:

-A Windows XP and above setting that will enable me to retreive the certificate  inside the smart card (along with some access to encryption/decryption capabilities to authenticate the certificate).

-Some sort of access to windows to allow me these options

-Perheps, Some sort of java pkcs#11 method that will enable me to get access to the same connection as Windows.

-Is such an ability vendor specific?

Is this even possible? The wikipedia Single sign-on entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on speaks of SSO with smartcards - but so far I haven't been able to find any way on how to do it. All I know is that my smartcard is prompts a second time if I try to use it with the regular pkcs#11 code.

To sum up:
1. Is there a windows/verndor specific/java to enable me to SSO using the smartcard.
2. If not or if not recommended, what other SSO solution should I use given that I don't want to depend on the Active directory people?
3. In the worst case, where SSO can only be efficiently acheived with Kerberose and ActiveDirectory - what implementation could be less demanding on the ActiveDirectory side?

Thank you.

Comment: "All I know is that my smartcard is prompts a second time if I try to use it with the regular pkcs#11 code." What do you mean by "the regular PKCS#11 code"? Is this Java code using the PKCS11 provider? On Windows system, Java also installs a [CAPI-based provider.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI) Have you researched that? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495392/java-security-mscapi-provider-how-to-use-without-password-popup) might be relevant.

Comment: I mean code that resembles - http://javaandcryptosmartcards.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/java-and-cryptographic-smartcards-this.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873666/pkcs11-sso-using-prior-windows-login-with-smartcard, we went down the GINA route, but take care, this takes a lot of time and requires signing by Microsoft.